# .indexOf for multiple results

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a text and I want to locate the positions of each comma. The string, a shorter version, would look like this:

```
string s = "A lot, of text, with commas, here and,there";
```

Ideally, I would use something like:

```
int[] i = s.indexOf(',');
```

but since indexOf only returns the first comma, I instead do:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
   if (s[i] == ',')
      list.Add(i);
}
```

Is there an alternative, more optimized way of doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to actually do here?

Comment: If you are doing this in order to separate the string later on, better use split.

Comment: @Shroedingers Cat - I am cleaning up the string to pass it on to a NLP library I am working on. The idea is to locate where they are, if they are used properly and if they are used in numbers, such as "3,14".

Comment: @Hyperboreus - I don't need to split them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Regex.Matches(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx) method. This will return a MatchCollection and then you could determine the Match.Index. MSDN has a good example,

using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = @"\b\w+es\b";
      string sentence = "Who writes these notes?";

      foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
         Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}", 
                           match.Value, match.Index);
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Found 'writes' at position 4
//       Found 'notes' at position 17
```

Comment: I was looking briefly at Regex but had no prior experience with itand couldn't work out how to use it. Let me try this.

Comment: Yep, that works. Will need to do a benchmark on it but will mark this as an answer in the meantime. This is a cleaner method if nothing else.

Comment: Make sure you save your regex in a static context.  Creating the regex initially is much more expensive than running the regex.

Comment: @Kyle W - Thanks for the tip, will do.

Answer (score 18):

Here I got a extension method for that, for the same use as `IndexOf`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string searchstring)
{
    int minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring);
    while (minIndex != -1)
    {
        yield return minIndex;
        minIndex = str.IndexOf(searchstring, minIndex + searchstring.Length);
    }
}
```

so you can use

```
s.AllIndexesOf(","); // 5    14    27    37
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/DZdQ0L

Comment: best and most elegant answer here imo

Comment: Imagine a case where `str` is `zzz` and searchstring is `zz`, this would only return `0` but the desire is likely `0` and `1`. One small fix to do this would me to `setMinIndex` to `str.IndexOf(searchstring, minIndex + 1);`

Answer (score 6):

[IndexOf also allows you to add another parameter for where to start looking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx). You can set that parameter to be the last known comma location +1. For example:

```
string s = "A lot, of text, with commas, here and, there";
int loc = s.IndexOf(',');
while (loc != -1) {
    Console.WriteLine(loc);
    loc = s.IndexOf(',', loc + 1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying with this earlier but read somewhere that this is actually a slower method than just doing the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the overload of the `IndexOf` method that also takes a start index to get the following comma, but you would still have to do that in a loop, and it would perform pretty much the same as the code that you have.

You could use a regular expression to find all commas, but that produces quite some overhead, so that's not more optimised than what you have.

You could write a LINQ query to do it in a different way, but that also has some overhead so it's not more optimised than what you have.

So, there are many alternative ways, but not any way that is more optimised.

Answer (score 0):

A bit unorthodox, but why not use a split? Might be less aggressive than iterating over the entire string

```
string longString = "Some, string, with, commas.";
string[] splitString = longString.Split(",");
int numSplits = splitString.Length - 1;
Debug.Log("number of commas "+numSplits);
Debug.Log("first comma index = "+GetIndex(splitString, 0)+" second comma index = "+GetIndex(splitString, 1));

public int GetIndex(string[] stringArray, int num)
{
    int charIndex = 0;
    for (int n = num; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        charIndex+=stringArray[n].Length;
    }
    return charIndex + num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way - a method that retrieves the string value that comes after a certain substring, in my case `id=` (*a string ID value, ending with a semi-colon*), where there were multiple id's in the larger string. And I wanted it to continue to the end.  Here's my method:

```
   public static List<string> GetAllIDsFromString(string largerString, string findThis)
   {
        List<string> listOfIDs = new List<string>();
        char lastChar = findThis.Last();
        do
        {
            string idSearch = largerString.Substring(largerString.IndexOf(findThis));
            string foundID = idSearch.Split(';')[0]?.Substring(idSearch.IndexOf(lastChar) + 1);
            idSearch = idSearch.Substring(idSearch.IndexOf(lastChar) + 1);
            listOfIDs.Add(foundID);
            largerString = idSearch;

         } while (largerString.IndexOf(findThis) > -1);

         return listOfIDs;
    }
```