# Add different text both to the start and end of double quotes in a string

Tags: c#, string

What can I do to add different text both to the start and end of double quotes in a string? let say I have this string

```
abc1 just "testing" some stuff
```

And I want to wrap the word/words within the double quotes in html span elements so I want the string to be something like this in the end

```
abc1 just <span class="myClass">"testing"</span> some stuff
```

So at the first `"` I want to add `<span class="myClass">` and at the second `"` I want to add `</span>`

How can I achieve this in C#?

Comment: You can use a regex or String.IndexOf as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865419/indexof-for-multiple-results) (there is even an example of extension method in one of the answers that will get you all the indexes) to find all occurences of specific character (double quotes in this case), and then iterate through them and replace every odd one with your first tag and every even one with second.

Comment: How about `Regex.Replace(input, "\"[^\"]+\"", match => $"<span class=\"myClass\">{match.Value}</span>")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **FSM** (**F**inite **S**tate **M**achine):

```
    private static string MyRoutine(string source) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      bool start = false; 

      foreach (char c in source) 
        if (c == '"') 
          if (start = !start)
            sb.Append("<span class=\"myClass\">\"");
          else
            sb.Append("\"</span>");
        else
          sb.Append(c);   

      return sb.ToString();  
    }
```

Then

```
    string source = "abc1 just \"testing\" some stuff";

    string result = MyRoutine(source);
```

Let's have a look

```
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome

```
    abc1 just <span class="myClass">"testing"</span> some stuff
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eMf53W) it yourself

Comment: Sneaky if-statement, with that valid single =  

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know there are exactly two quotes in the string, you can do this:

```
using System;

var input = "abc1 just \"testing\" some stuff";

var split = input.Split('"');
var result = $"{split[0]}<span class=\"myClass\">\"{split[1]}\"</span>{split[2]}";

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
abc1 just <span class="myClass">"testing"</span> some stuff
```

[Try it online](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOyQExAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKBoDcIEACAS0wAd0YmBeJgIgjAAxuSYArdLCYAdfvFhsA5nKZQA9mDhqY6AGZ7+Abhr1Ga9gBsW3Pm04wAdAGUrNgBQByfp4CUJ6gZmBDgodEtbJgASfgBvKDcYAG0ABgBdAF8AHgSITCYyHjkwAE8AYUtoKDkAPjl4xKTyTLksgHpczBqG62TSTONTamJyAE53ELCI/yA===).