# How do I find indexes of a character if it occurs multiple times in a string?

Tags: c#, string

I need to find all indexes of a character in a string. I tried using  `Input.IndexOf`,
but it only returns the index of the first occurrence of the character. I need a way of indexing where I can input a string like `"abcabc"` and get the position of both a's, like: `0 3`. How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Finding all positions of substring in a larger string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-substring-in-a-larger-string-in-c-sharp), [.indexOf for multiple results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6865419/8967612)

Comment: [`IndexOf(Char, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_Char_System_Int32_)